# cover a sphere with 3 open semispheres

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Why is it impossible to cover a sphere that has radius $R$ with $3$ open semispheres of radius $R$? In my mind I have the pictorial image of the situation, but I can't find a formal proof.

Comment: What do you mean by cover ?

Comment: If $S$ is the sphere (so a suface), and $U_i$ are the semispheres (so surfaces), I mean that $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^3 U_i$

Comment: ok. Now I understand.

Comment: Open means an open set (topological)?

Comment: yes I mean open set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The union of two such semi-spheres always leaves an antipodal pair uncovered (where their boundaries intersect).  This pair cannot be covered by a third semi-sphere since that does not contain any antipodal pair.